# Heroku assets do not update in precompilation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, precompiled

I'm not able to update my css on Heroku. Here's the cenario:

My precompiled css is the same since first push to heroku.
When I run rake assets:precompile, it does compile successfully and even gives me a new application css file (different hash) on console. But then when I go to public/assets, there is the same css from before.

With assets:clean I get the same result. If I delete manually the css goes away, but it doesn't fall back to pipeline and loads the same css file. When I run precompile again, there it is... same file, same hash.

The strangest thing is when I tail my css files inside heroku it shows me the correct changes so the push was actually successful (the same with other files).

I tried also clearing heroku cache following this: [clear cache with buildpack](http://mikeslinn.blogspot.com.br/2013/03/cleaning-heroku-cache.html)

Also ran the same commands from above using RAILS_ENV=production and restarted the dynos many times and cleared browser cache many times with different browsers.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Perhaps you could give us a link to your Heroku app?

Comment: I would try using `rake assets:clobber` (deletes precompiled assets) on your local system, then running `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` before pushing to heroku again

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot... seems like I forgot the basics =D.
But tell me: shouldn't heroku un rake assets:clean and heroku run rake assets:precompile remove my precompiled assets in heroku?